# ndarray.tranpose(2,0,1) producing unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x, transpose, numpy-ndarray

I'm working with numpy arrays and learning how tranpose works. I'm seeing an odd result though. Below is initializing my array.

```py
matB = np.array([i for i in range(24)]).reshape((2,3,4))
matB.shape
```

output: (2, 3, 4)

I expect the below will result in an array with shape (3,4,2), but that isn't the output.

```py
matB.transpose(2,0,1).shape
```

Expected output: (3,4,2)

Actual output: (4, 2, 3)

I expected the second transpose to change the axes in the order I provided in tranpose(2,0,1), but what I'm receiving is what I would expect if I provided transpose(1,2,0).

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: You specify that you want axis 2 to be first, then axis 0, then axis 1. Axis 2 is of size 4 in your example. Axis 0 is of size 2. Axis 1 is of size 3. Hence you get `(4,2,3)` as output.

Comment: That makes sense, I was thinking that the arguments that you provide determine where the current axes end up. As in the first int would specify where the 0th dimension goes, not the order of the dimensions. That makes more sense, thanks!